# Is the position of "still" and usage of a parenthetical element grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar

Earlier today I was commenting on something and typed:

> This, to me, smells as incomplete still.

I quickly change it to:

> This still smells as incomplete to me.

As a native in English I rely mostly on intuition to determine if something is correct. And when I read over my comment, I found the former hard to understand, and so made be doubt if it is grammatically correct. I'm rather fond of *parenthetical elements* and so believe that both positions of "to me" are grammatically correct.

However I can't find how "still" is being used grammatically in either sentence. And so I can't tell if the former is correct or incorrect.

Comment: This feels like two different senses of the adverb *still*. The first one reads a bit like *still* in its sense of *nevertheless*, as a sentence adverb: *Still, this, to me, smells as incomplete.* The second one reads like *still*'s more usual sense: used to "indicate the continuance of an action or condition." [See *still* senses 3 and 4 under adverb in Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/still).

Comment: @TinfoilHat Hmm. Yes, that sounds correct.